# JavaScript Mini Game Using OOP

Tags: javascript

Consider the code below:

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();

(function () {
    var FPS = 60;
    var DEFAULT_WIDTH = 600;
 
    function drawBoard(){
        this.dimensions = drawBoard.defaultDimensions;
        this.config = drawBoard.config;
        this.init();
    }

    drawBoard.config ={
        ACCELERATION: 0.001,
        INITIAL_BOUNCE_VELOCITY: 12,
        MIN_JUMP_HEIGHT: 35,
    }
    drawBoard.defaultDimensions = {
        WIDTH: DEFAULT_WIDTH,
        HEIGHT: 150
    };

    drawBoard.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            this.adjustDimensions();
            this.containerEl = document.getElementById('canvasBox');
            this.canvas = createCanvas(this.containerEl, this.dimensions.WIDTH, this.dimensions.HEIGHT, 0);
            this.canvasCtx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
            this.canvasCtx.fillStyle = '#f7f7f7';
            this.canvasCtx.fill();
           
        },
        adjustDimensions: function() { 
                this.canvas.width = this.dimensions.WIDTH;
                this.canvas.height = this.dimensions.HEIGHT;
        }
    }

    function createCanvas(container, width, height, opt_classname) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id = "myCanvas";
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        container.appendChild(canvas);
        return canvas
    }

}());
new drawBoard();
```

In summary, I'm trying to create a mini game using canvas.

I'm trying to make it easy on myself by breaking things into parts, then linking them together.

However, I keep getting this is not defined for basically everything (starting with drawboard at the bottom).

I'm trying to follow an example [here](https://chromedino.com/), but I can't see how they pulled it off, and why when following the example it's not working for me.

I see JavaScript source from the page (is to large to post here).

It all makes sense, until I go to run my code and does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, check out what they're doing directly after defining the function Runner. They're adding it to the window object. That's what lets them call it directly at the bottom.

Try starting with this:

```
function drawBoard(){
    this.dimensions = drawBoard.defaultDimensions;
    this.config = drawBoard.config;
    this.init();
}

window['drawBoard'] = drawBoard;
```

Comment: ok great, I've been toying with it a lot. And at one point I did have that in my code too. I'm new to javascript, but I like the modular style the example code is written in. I appreciate you showing me some direction.

Comment: tested it out, and that did the trick. Something so simple... Thanks again for the assist.